# Saving columns under separate headers in a text file to separate lists

Tags: python, text

I have the following text-file:

```
File A
am001 G13 
am002 U13
am003 A15

File B
am001 C15
am002 U2715
am003 G32
```

I would like to save the column values under the separate headers to separate lists. For example, the output should look something like this:

```
filea_id = ['am001', 'am002', 'am003']
filea_values = ['G13', 'U13', 'A15']
fileb_id = ['am001', 'am002', 'am003']
fileb_values = ['C15', 'U2715', 'G32']
```

How can I do this using python?

Comment: Your problem is to parse the file or to write file with new data? Both?

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich Both. But mainly I want to know how to separate the columns under the different headers. I couldn't figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example where itertools meets up to its expectation.

**Implementation**

```
def foo():
    from itertools import izip, imap, takewhile
    with open("temp.txt") as fin:
        def skip(fin):
            # Take/Read all lines from the file and discard which are empty
            takewhile(lambda name: name.strip() == "", fin)
        try:
            while fin:
                # Skip all empty lines
                skip(fin)
                # The next line is the file name
                fname = next(fin).strip()
                # All subsequent lines until the empty line is the content
                # Split the lines and transpose it 
                # Yield the file name and the transposed content
                yield fname, zip(*(imap(str.split, takewhile(lambda n:n.strip(), fin))))
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

**Demo**

```
>>> content ={}
>>> for fname, data in foo():
    content[fname]=data


>>> content
{'File A': [('am001', 'am002', 'am003'), ('G13', 'U13', 'A15')], 'File B': [('am001', 'am002', 'am003'), ('C15', 'U2715', 'G32')]}
```

**Explanation**

```
[Skip All Empty Lines]                                  [Split each line]     [Transpose]      
    V        
    V        
[The Next Line is the File Name]  fname =  File A                                 
[Read Until an empty line]                 am001 G13       am001 | G13      am001 am002 am003
    V                                      am002 U13 >>>   am002 | U13  >>> G13   U13   A15
    V                                      am003 A15       am003 | A15
[Skip All Empty Lines]
    V
    V    
[The Next Line is the File Name]  fname =  File B           
[Read Until an empty line]                 am001 C15       am001 | C15        am001 am002 am003
    V                                      am002 U2715 >>> am002 | U2715  >>> C15   U2715 G32
    V                                      am003 G32       am003 | G32
```

Comment: This achieves the task that I want to do. I would accept this as the answer if you could explain a bit about the code in Implementation. Thanks :)

Comment: @TheEmperor: Understanding how each meta function works with python built-in and libraries is beyond the scope of the answer. It would require you to study the python manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.deque` to store your specific lines then use `split` and `zip` to get the expected result :

```
from collections import deque
d=deque(maxlen=3)
with open('output.txt') as f:
    for line in f :
        if line != '\n' and 'File' not in line :
              d.append(line)
        if len(d)==3:
             filea_id ,filea_values =zip(*[i.split() for i in d])
             print filea_id ,filea_values
             d.clear()
             #or do stuff with filea_id ,filea_values
```

Result:

```
('am001', 'am002', 'am003') ('G13', 'U13', 'A15')
('am001', 'am002', 'am003') ('C15', 'U2715', 'G32')
```

Comment: This works too but the output is not quite what I wanted. If I understand correctly, in your code, you are grouping the columns under header File A and File B together. I want them to be separate. How can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to read and parse your source file. If your source file have only two columns, the code is very simple.

File's content is:

```
am001 G13 
am002 U13
am003 A15
```

To parse it, do:

```
data = {}

with open("src.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        key, value = line.split()
        data[key] = value

print data
```

This will produce dictionary:

```
{'am003': 'A15', 'am002': 'U13', 'am001': 'G13'}
```

Now you can loop over dictionary, and build your own format for viewing or writing to another file as this:

```
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    print key, value
```